# How to connect to IRC through a proxy?

Tags: php

I wrote a script that connects to an IRC server using sockets, but how would I connect through a proxy? I thought it might be possible using curl, but it seems it's more suited to HTTP and doesn't support continuously sending packets. I thought it would be as simple as connecting to the proxy through fsockopen() and sending the packets through, but how do I tell the proxy (SOCKS 4/5) to connect to the IRC server? I can't fsockopen() inside fsockopen(), if you know what I mean (probably not).

Any help or ideas or whatever?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that:
http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.fsockopen.php#82586
Should do what you want ;-)

Comment: That's for HTTP requests which can be done much easier with cURL and doesn't help me at all.

Comment: You have to adapt it ... It should be possible to do it on base of that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your first command after opening the socket to your proxy would be 'CONNECT irc.whatever.com:6667' and then continue as if you were connected directly to the irc server.

I'm not exactly sure of the exact SOCKS commands.

Comment: $socket = fsockopen("222.124.8.13", 8000);
fputs($socket,"CONNECT irc.server.com:6667\n");
fputs($socket,"NICK $nick \n");
fputs($socket,"USER $nick bot.com Bot :Bot\n"); 

http://aliveproxy.com/irc-proxy-checker/?i=222.124.8.13&p=8000. Proxy is up but it's not connecting. Problem?